# Unit tests not showing code coverage with async/await

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, moq

I'm using vs2017 and none of my unit tests are showing code coverage. I"m using async/await and MOQ.

```
[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("SeriesRepository")]
public void GetSeriesAsyncShouldReturnSeriesId12345()
{
    var repositoryMock = new Mock<ISeriesRepository>();

    var seriesId = "12345";
    var channel = 75864;            

    var mockSeries = new Mock<ISeries>();
    mockSeries.SetupGet(x => x.SeriesId).Returns("12345");

    repositoryMock
        .Setup(x => x.GetSeriesAsync(seriesId, channel))
        .ReturnsAsync(mockSeries.Object);

    var result = repositoryMock.Object.GetSeriesAsync(seriesId, channel).Result;

    result.SeriesId.Should().Be(seriesId);
}
```

Comment: You appear to only be calling mocked methods, which wouldn't result in any non-test code being called. What code are you expecting to be covered by this test that isn't showing as covered?

Comment: Are you asking why your *unit test code* isn't shown as covered or why your *actual logic code* isn't shown as covered? If the former, please ensure your tests actually run. If the latter, **where** are you calling your actual logic code? It seems you're setting up a mock, then ensuring the mock behave as you mocked it. What is your actual logic code that you want to test here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First fact is that you are not actually testing anything in your test as you simply create mocks and invoke the mocks.

You are simply testing that the mocking framework works as advertised.

Secondly the tests can be made async as well to allow the test to exercise sequentially.

```
[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("SeriesRepository")]
public async Task GetSeriesAsyncShouldReturnSeriesId12345() {
    var repositoryMock = new Mock<ISeriesRepository>();

    var seriesId = "12345";
    var channel = 75864;            

    var mockSeries = new Mock<ISeries>();
    mockSeries.Setup(_ => _.SeriesId).Returns(seriesId);

    repositoryMock
        .Setup(_ => _.GetSeriesAsync(seriesId, channel))
        .ReturnsAsync(mockSeries.Object);

    var result = await repositoryMock.Object.GetSeriesAsync(seriesId, channel);

    result.SeriesId.Should().Be(seriesId);
}
```

What is suppose to happen is that you mock the dependencies of a target under test to behave as expected in order to verify some desired behavior

Lets say we wanted to test a target method of a class. Something like

```
public class SeriesService {
    private readonly ISeriesRepository repository;

    public SeriesService(ISeriesRepository repository
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public async Task<ISeries> GetSeries(string seriesId, int channel) {
        var series = await repository.GetSeriesAsync(seriesId, channel);

        //...do some other stuff

        return series;
    }
}
```

An example test would then look like this

```
[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("SeriesRepository")]
public async Task TargetMethodShouldReturnSeriesId12345() {
    //Assert
    var repositoryMock = new Mock<ISeriesRepository>();

    var seriesId = "12345";
    var channel = 75864;            

    var mockSeries = new Mock<ISeries>();
    mockSeries.Setup(_ => _.SeriesId).Returns(seriesId);

    repositoryMock
        .Setup(_ => _.GetSeriesAsync(seriesId, channel))
        .ReturnsAsync(mockSeries.Object);

    var target = new SeriesService(repositoryMock.Object);

    //Act
    var result = await target.GetSeries(seriesId, channel);

    //Assert
    result.Should().NotBeNull();
    result.SeriesId.Should().Be(seriesId);
}
```

Comment: I'm confused about the the TargetClass. TargetClass would be similar to my SeriesService Class. My SeriesService Class expects an ISeriesRepository to be injected.

Comment: @user3582849 that could be correct. Show an example of that class so we can work out an isolated unit test for it.

Comment: Thank you. That did it. 
What this be considered a Repository Test or Service Test?
I had created a test class called SeriesRepositoryTest, 
If this is testing the repostory, how should I be testing the service layer?

Comment: @user3582849 this unit test tests the `SeriesService` in isolation. The repository in this case is an explicit dependency that was mocked in order to allow the system under test to be tested in isolation with out knock on effect of using an actual repository implementation.

Comment: This is for a web api and I also have a controller. What do you suggest for unit testing with this? Would it make sense to write a unit test that tests the controller instead?
The ISeriesService is injected into the controller.

Comment: @user3582849 each layer would require their own tests for greater code coverage. Controllers can also be tested in isolation as well mocking their respective dependencies.

Comment: ok then one last question. Originally, I was trying to write a unit test for the repository. The original code I had posted.
The example test you posted also includes the target class SeriesService.
Is your example a Service Layer test or Repository Layer test? How does the repository layer test differ then the Service layer?

Comment: @user3582849 service layer test, given that the subject of the test is a service layer implementation which happens to have dependencies on repository layer abstractions. To test repository layer implementations you basically follow the same format.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any wait for your repositoryMock setup to complete.  So, your test case is ending before your async calls are complete.

Make sure you wait by adding:

```
repositryMock.setup(...).ReturnsAsync(...).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Or

```
repositryMock.setup(...).ReturnsAsync(...).Result;
```

Or

```
repositryMock.setup(...).ReturnsAsync(...).Wait();
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: You mean, apart from reading `.Result` which is a blocking call? (*should be* a blocking call, if indeed any tasks are involved).

Comment: Yes, we should make this blocking call; so as to ensure that all involved tasks are executed before the next call happens.   And if your test method is Async then you can await on it rather than blocking the call.